# Syntax understanding (Unique index with partitions)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

What does the followin "PARTFIELD" represent in that syntax?

```
CREATE TABLE Z_TAB_PART
(
    PARTFIELD            DATE NULL ,
    NAME                 VARCHAR2(20) NULL 
)
    PARTITION BY RANGE (PARTFIELD)
    (PARTITION init VALUES LESS THAN (to_date('20131201','yyyymmdd')));

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX XAK1Z_TAB_PART ON Z_TAB_PART
(PARTFIELD   ASC,NAME   ASC)
     LOCAL ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PARTFIELD` is just the name of the column; they seem to have picked that name to indicate that it's the field that the table will be partitioned on. So it's used in the `PARTITION` range clause, and it is indexed.

In the [partition by range syntax diagram](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF54415), the `column` that refers just happens to be called `PARTFIELD` in this example.

In the `create index` statement, the same column name is used in the [index expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_5012.htm#SQLRF53989).

Comment: The same column is used for both. There is a unique index on the column that the tale is partitioned by.